# Unresolved Identifier in Function Call in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm very new to this and after a lot of searching on "Unresolved identifier" I have not seem to get this error to go away. The "unresolved identifier" error is occurring in the function call in "viewDidLoad()" where it says "startGame()".

I am basing this on this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/114262/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-4-your-first-app

The function is supposed to start the countdown timer when the app launches.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
           startGame()
    //SecondTimerValue.delegate = self
    SecondTimerValue.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func startGame() {
        seconds = 30
        count = 0
        FirstTimerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(count)"

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("subtractTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

Here is the entire code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var FirstTimerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var SecondTimerValue: UITextField!
var count = 0
var seconds = 0
var timer = NSTimer()
var SecondTimerValueVar = 0

// Goal 1 - verify input in text field went to variable
// Goal 2 - get rid of keyboard after "enter"
// Goal 3 - use new value to start new timer
// Goal 4 - When 1st timer reaches zero, start second timer



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
           startGame()
    //SecondTimerValue.delegate = self
    SecondTimerValue.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func buttonPressed(){
    SecondTimerValueVar = SecondTimerValue.text.toInt()!
    scoreLabel.text = "Score \(count)"
    count++
}

@IBAction func startTimerPressed(){
    //let SecondTimerValueVar = Int(SecondTimerValue)

}

@IBAction func userTappedBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(true)


//let a:Int? = Int(firstText.text)     // firstText is //UITextField
//let b:Int? = Int(secondText.text)   // secondText is UITextField

func startGame() {
        seconds = 30
        count = 0
        FirstTimerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(count)"

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("subtractTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


func subtractTime (){
    seconds--
    FirstTimerLabel.text = "Time: \(seconds)"

    if (seconds==0) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark @matt's answer as correct since it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@IBAction func userTappedBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(true)
func startGame() {
```

You've left out the closing curly brace for `userTappedBackground`, so `startGame` is *inside it* and can't be seen as a method.

Comment: Resolved! Thank you!

Comment: @Jon Proper indentation will help you identify problems such as that more easily. If you see a weird error like that, have Xcode reindent all of the code in the file for you using control-i.